# Antlr Cpp templated visitor class

Tags: antlr, antlr4, expressionvisitor

Is there any possibility of templated visitors in AntlrCpp similar to Java implementation?
I've a `BaseExpression` class that I want to return from my visitors but for the sub-rules, I'd like to return `ScalarExpression/VectorExpression` that derive from `BaseExpression`. Now, I've to check the type of `Any` everytime I need to do something specific related to `scalar` or `vector` rules. Having a template would eliminate the need for `Any` and we can directly access the right type of object returned from each visitor method.

Comment: A template class would limit the entire visitor to a single return type. `Any` is much more flexible.

Comment: I think the C++ version doesn't have templated visitors because it's just not possible - at least not using the usual virtual-inheritance implementation of the visitor pattern - because virtual functions can't be templated. So it'd be impossible to define an `accept` function that accepts a templated visitor. So not only can't you get it to generate a templated visitor class, it'd be also impossible to define one yourself - even when not using ANTLR at all.

Comment: @MikeLischke You could still use `Visitor<Any>` if you wanted that flexibility though, couldn't you? At least as long as the ANTLR runtime still shipped with `Any` or you used `boost::any` instead. If it is possible to have a templated visitor, I'd agree with OP that it'd be a good idea to have it.

Comment: Could we have `Any::get()` that just returns the same reference/ptr that was returned from a visitor method? That way I won't need multiple checks for `visit(ctx->expression()).is<scalar>()` and `visit(ctx->expression()).is<vector>()` when I just need to get the object that was returned.

Comment: That's something we should discuss in the ANTLR4 repo, not on SO. Create a pull request with your suggestion and I take a look. This question here should be closed.